# Spree install error "spree (>=0) x86-mingw32 depends on thor (=0.15.4)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, thor

Installing spree on rails gives multiple errors for dependence on 'thor' although I have both versions in my gem list.

#

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thor":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (>=0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      thor (= 0.14.6) x86-mingw32

```
sass-rails (~> 3.23) x86-mingw32 depends on 
  thor (= 0.15.4)
```

#

NOTE: My versions used are:

rails 3.2.6

spree 1.1.2

ruby 1.9.3p194

Answer (score 0):

Although you're asking about a specific install error, I'm assuming that since it sounds like you're setting up a development environment that the following could be helpful:

Setting Spree up on Windows can be a little bit of a pain, and using Vagrant and VirtualBox is a good way around the issues.  This Vagrant setup and bootstrap script installs more recent versions of Rails, Ruby and Spree, but you should be able to modify it to your taste (focus on bootstrap.sh):

https://github.com/nurelm/spree_vagrant